Выравнивание объектов в памяти в соответствии с ISO/IEC 9899:2024
Поясните, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю это понятие.
Выдержка из стандарта про термин alignment:

Requirement that objects of a particular type be located on storage boundaries with addresses that are particular multiples of a byte address.

Перевод:

Требование, чтобы объекты определенного типа располагались на границах хранилища с адресами, которые являются конкретными кратными байтового адреса.

Я понимаю это так, что значение любой переменной в памяти реализация должна распределить на целое число байт, то есть структура с битовым полем, меньшим байта, будет занимать один или более байтов, правильно?

Это про другое. Ваша цитата про то, что некоторые типы должны иметь адрес кратный N байт (обычно для встроенных типов N = sizeof(тип), но не больше sizeof(void*)).

Не правильно понимаете. Попросту говоря, alignment это про то, что адрес (как целое число) должен быть кратен размеру. Например, short (2 байта), должен располагаться по четным адресам, double  (8 байт) надо размещать по адресам кратным 8-ми (т.е. 3 младших бита такого адреса д.б. нулями) и т.п.

О том, как значения хранятся в памяти, говорится в разделе

6.2.6 Representations of types
4
Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type are represented using n×CHAR_BIT bits, where n is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. An object that has the value may be copied into an object of type unsigned char [n] (e.g. by memcpy); the resulting set of bytes is called the object
representation of the value. Values stored in bit-fields consist of m bits, where m is the size specified for the bit-field. The object representation is the set of m bits the bit-field comprises in the addressable storage unit holding it.

